# Can I see the precise breakdown of the achievements' percentage obtained in Steam?

Tags: steam, achievements

When viewing achievements on Steam it shows a percentage number for each achievement, which is the number of players that have unlocked that particular achievement.

Is there any way to view the actual data behind these percentages?

For example, *Pillars of Eternity*'s I think Triple Crown's (0.1%) is not equals to Triple Crown Solo's (0.1%)

Comment: Lacking the knowlage about Pilars of Eternity achievements, I don't quite understand what you are asking here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can view precise percentages for each achievement at the URL below.

http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetGlobalAchievementPercentagesForApp/v0002/?gameid=291650

Change the number at the end to the appid of the game. You can find that as the number in the URL of the store page for the game you're interested in. You can not view the number of people who achieved it out of a total number of players.

Comment: can I see the number of users of the game?

Comment: @Herokiller I already addressed that in my original answer.